# Standard container/Library for storing the window of numbers and returning the number of unique ones?

Tags: c++, std

I am looking for a standard container/library in C++ with following functionalities:

1. Storing the windows of numbers (enqueue and dequeue are enough).
2. Returning the number of unique numbers in the window.

It can be something merging std::queue and std::set capabilities.

EDITED:
Example expected operation. For this sequence '1 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 6 6 7 7 8' and window size of 2 we would have following steps:

1. Window = [1 2], unique ones = 2
2. Window = [2 3], unique ones = 2
3. Window = [3 3], unique ones = 1
4. Window = [3 4], unique ones = 2
5. and so on ...

Comment: What do you mean by 'window of numbers'? May I suggest using an std::map, maybe? A map<int, int> may do what you want. The key is the number you're checking, the second one is the 'count'.

Comment: by window of numbers I meant a queue of numbers already.

Comment: Will you keep duplicate elements?

Comment: I don't think there's any container, that can do that without further logic. The only way to do that is increase a count (with map), then iterate through the collection and output all, where the count is '1'. Would that work?

Comment: Yeap, I think the combination of queue and map would work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want two containers:

- a `deque<number>` to store the numbers in the window in order;
- a `map<number, size_t>` (or `unordered_map` if available) to store the count of each unique number.

Then your operations are:

```
void push(number n) {
    deque.push_back(n);
    ++map[n];
}

void pop() {
    auto found = map.find(deque.front());
    assert(found != map.end());
    assert(found->second > 0);
    if (--found->second == 0) {
        map.erase(found);
    }
    deque.pop_front();
}

size_t count_unique() {
    return map.size();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Mike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/204847/mike-seymour), here is the complete class:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

using namespace std;
#include "map"
#include "deque"

class window{
    private:
        std::deque<int> numbers;
        std::map<int, size_t> unique;
    public:
        window(){};
        void push(int n) {
            numbers.push_back(n);
            ++unique[n];
        }

        void pop() {
            map<int, size_t>::iterator found = unique.find(numbers.front());
            assert(found != unique.end());
            assert(found->second > 0);
            if (--found->second == 0) {
                unique.erase(found);
            }
            numbers.pop_front();
        }

        size_t count_unique() {
            return unique.size();
        }
};
```

And this is the test case:

```
int main(){
    // example list '1 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 6 6 7 7 8'
    int list[13] = {1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8};
    window w1;
    w1.push(list[0]);w1.push(list[1]);

    int i=0;
    printf("The list is: ");
    for(i=0; i<13; i++){
        printf("%d ",list[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    for(i=0; i<11; i++){
        printf("[%d] Unique ones: %d\n",i+1,w1.count_unique());
        w1.push(list[i+2]);w1.pop();
    }

    return 0;
}
```